# Concatenating two values then update to one field

Tags: validation, salesforce

I am new person in salesforce can you please help me .

I have one custom filed **opportunityName** this is auto number field,In this field i have to add two fields values those two are pick list fields. `(Like:opportunityName-field1-field2)` 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Autonumber fields are generated by the system and that's it. You can change their format (to include some prefix or dates, so you could have `OPP-00123` or `OPP-2013-05-01`). They won't allow you to use pieces of other fields though, they'll be always just that - number with some (identical) formatting applied to it.

If your field should be always calculated and not directly writeable for your users - I'd suggest a formula field. If what you're after has to offer option of changing (for example for System Administrators) - then probably a text field + workflow would field update would be best.

You can read more about field types & workflows by simply going to "Help & Support" in your Salesforce instance. You can also go to Customize -> Opportunities -> Fields (or Create -> Workflow Rules) and hit "Help for this page" link in the upper right corner.

The formula (which can be either used directly in the formula field or as part of the workflow) will most likely look like `Name + '-' + TEXT(Field1__c) + '-' + TEXT(Field2__c)`.

So - now you should at least have some keywords you can use to search for solutiions :) If you're a new System Administrator I strongly recommend going through some of the youtube videos and online trainings they've provided in "Help & Training".